# Uninstalling Office from Mac

Tags: macos

I've been using Windows till now. Now I got MacBook.

I am new to OS X.

I'm facing difficulties when trying to uninstall Office from Mac.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have googled, here is the first link on Google Search.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2398768

Comment: Why do you answer this? This is not programming related. Your answer should have been a comment.

Comment: I've already flagged the question anyways.